# TLS tunnel for Outlook 365

Tags: debian, ssl, stunnel

We have here an old helpdesk software that only speaks imaps using the now obsolete SSLv3. Obviously, such protocol is no longer accepted by Outlook 365.

I proposed to install a TLS tunnel/applicational proxy using Debian Stretch as a broker to be able to speak with Outlook 365, so the application will talk IMAP to one end of the tunnel, and the other end will talk with a more modern encryption to Outlook 365.

I installed the required package with:

```
sudo apt-get install stunnel4
```

And enabled TLS editing /etc/default/stunnel4

```
ENABLED=1
```

What do I need to do more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf file based on the example file for a gmail tunnel (gmail-imap rule at `/usr/share/doc/stunnel4/examples/stunnel.conf-sample`):

```
[outlook365-imap]
client = yes
accept = 1.1.1.1:143
connect = outlook.office365.com:993
verifyChain = no
```

whereas 1.1.1.1 is the IP address of the interface of the tunnel server.

Then I started stunnel with:

```
sudo service stunnel4 start
```

To check the tunnel is working, telnet to it:

```
$telnet 1.1.1.1 143
Trying 1.1.1.1...
Connected to 1.1.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [VgBJADEAUABSADAANwBDAEEAMAAxADcAMQAuAGUAdQByAHAAcgBkADAANwAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
A1 LOGOUT
* BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 IMAP4 server signing off.
A1 OK LOGOUT completed.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

With this output we confirm the TLS tunnel is indeed working properly.

We also tested it with an Outlook Windows client pointed to 1.1.1.1:143 before pointing the application to the tunnel. It works well.

Adenda for begginers: why this works? Because most of the "new" secure Internet protocols are built using the old plaintext protocols with an added layer of encryption.