# How can I connect to an SSL-only website with a non-SSL-aware program?

Tags: proxy, ssl

I have a program on CentOS 6 that connects to a server online. I believe the server has been upgraded to require SSL, but my program version does not support that and I cannot easily build a newer version.

It seems to me that I could run a proxy on localhost, send HTTP requests to that, and have that send HTTP/TLS requests to the actual server.

Is it possible to use SSLProxyEngine in Apache ?

Comment: see related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382000/tls-tunnel-for-outlook-365 ; maybe a duplicate except that it is for Debian.